# How to use an unordered map with lists as a values

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, dictionary

I am trying to figure out how to maneuver around an unordered map with lists as a values. Is it possible to assign a list to a value by specified string key and then later add to that list some value or modify it or replace entire list? I also do not understand how you would print the specific list either.

Example:

```
std::unordered_map <string, list<int> > testmap;
list<int> templist;
templist.pushfront(10);
templist.pushfront(5);
testmap["First"] = templist;
```

How would I print the list templist from the unordered map and how can I add onto the list after its been assigned to "First"

Comment: You cannot modify map keys. You can only erase the element and create a new one. Why do you need a map with lists as keys anyway?

Comment: Please edit your question to show an example of the code you would *like* to be able to use -- even if it doesn't compile.

Comment: I should have made it more clear that the keys are not lists, but each key will have a list associated with it. The description is updated.

Comment: You might want to [edit] the specific question you are asking here..  Are you really looking for an answer to "Is it possible?"  That seems to be the only question here and the answer to that is "Yes".  Otherwise, we're guessing what the **real** question is.

Comment: @FawksMulder What's your particular problem when using this code example? You can add to the `std::list` as usual, as soon you acceass it by key. Printing a list is done in a loop as usual unless you provide a `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const std::list&)` overload (which would imply a loop).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the post again.

Comment: `testmap["First"].pushfront(42);` will work. Note that operator `[]` will create a default initialized (empty in this case) `list`, so you could operate entirely on `testmap["First"]` and not have a `templist` at all if you chose.

Comment: @FawksMulder Now after your edit your question did completely change it's direction. You should change your question title thoroughly, otherwise your question doen't have any value for future research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I print the list templist from the unordered map and how can
>   I add onto the list after its been assigned to "First"

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::list<int>> testmap;

    std::list<int> templist;

    templist.push_front( 10 );
    templist.push_front( 5 );

    testmap["First"] = templist;

    for ( const auto &item : testmap["First"] ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    testmap["First"].push_front( 0 );

    for ( const auto &item : testmap["First"] ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
5 10 
0 5 10
```

Or you can even use for example an ordinary loop (or a standard algorithm like std::copy) to output the list.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>


int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::list<int>> testmap;

    std::list<int> templist;

    templist.push_front( 10 );
    templist.push_front( 5 );

    testmap["First"] = templist;

    for ( auto first = testmap["First"].begin(); first != testmap["First"].end(); ++first ) std::cout << *first << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    testmap["First"].push_front( 0 );

    for ( auto first = testmap["First"].begin(); first != testmap["First"].end(); ++first ) std::cout << *first << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
5 10 
0 5 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do with an unordered map with a list as a value as you need.

For example for such definitions:

```cpp
std::unordered_map <string, list<int> > testmap;
list<int> templist;
```

you can:

- replace or create entire list value:

```cpp
testmap["First"] = templist;
```

- print some list item

```cpp
std::cout << (*testmap["First"].begin()) << endl;
```

- or print all items

```cpp
for (auto v : testmap["First"])
  std::cout << v << "\n";
```

- replace some list value

```cpp
std::replace(testmap["First"].begin(), testmap["First"].end(), 20, 99)
```